# Anonymous function reintroduces possible undefined type error even though I narrow it down

Tags: typescript

```
  if (orig && dest) {

    let pickup = drops_orig(orig, drops)

    if (!pickup) {
      return undefined
    }

    return pickup_drop(pickup, drops)
      .find(_ => equal(_.drop.orig, dest))
  }
```

usage of `dest` inside `find` throws this type error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Pos | undefined' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'Pos'.
```

It complains because `dest` maybe `undefined`, even though I check it in the first line. I think this happens in anonymous functions. What is the idiomatic way to circumvent this?

If I do this it works but it's excessive:

```
if (dest) {
  let _dest = dest
  // find(_ => use_okdest(_dest))
}
```

Comment: Using find method return a specific type (related to arguemts of array) and undefined. you can use `as` keyword to define type of variable implicity.

Comment: If you're sure that callback don't have side effect on variable - you can just use non-null assertion operator: `equal(_.drop.orig, dest!)`. Other option would be copying to `const` variable.